# Attempting to get the value of a property via Reflection, the property is null

Tags: c#, .net-core

Given some code like this:

```
var deepPropertyName = "QuizSubmissionEvents"
T fullResult = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(content, JsonSnakeCaseNameStrategySettings.Settings());
var prop = fullResult.GetType().GetProperty(deepPropertyName);
var properties = fullResult.GetType().GetProperties();
var value = prop.GetValue(fullResult);
```

`prop` is null and I can't figure out why.  The following screenshot shows, I believe, shows that `fullResult` does have the `QuizSubmissionEvents` property:

[screenshot detailing issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kilWe.png)

This is the class which is represented by `T` here (PlatformQuizSubmissionEvents)

```
public class PlatformQuizSubmissionEvents
    {
        public List<PlatformQuizSubmissionEvent> QuizSubmissionEvents;
    }

    public class PlatformQuizSubmissionEvent
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public string EventType { get; set; }

        public DateTime ClientTimestamp { get; set; }

        [JsonConverter(typeof(CustomArrayConverter<EventData>))]
        public List<EventData> EventData { get; set; }
    }

    public class EventData
    {
        public string? QuizQuestionId { get; set; }

        public string? Answer { get; set; }
    }
```

As I understand it, I should be able to access the value of `fullResult.QuizSubmissionEvents` in this way but, again, `GetProperty()` is returning null.

Here is a simplified fiddle which reproduces the error: https://dotnetfiddle.net/r36pRG

Comment: `QuizSubmissionEvents` in your code appears to be a public field, not a public property. Can you see it if you use `fullResult.GetType().GetField(deepPropertyName)`?

Comment: @pmcoltrane you're right! I changed it to use the AutoProperty feature 
`public List<PlatformQuizSubmissionEvent> QuizSubmissionEvents {get;set;}` and now the code works as expected.